# JSPM and private server endpoint?

Tags: jspm, systemjs

I have GitLab installed on an internal development server. I would like to use it as a distribution endpoint for jspm during development. It is possible to define which git server you use in JSPM or is there some other way to use packages from a private source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/Orbs/jspm-git – "A generic jspm registry for Git Repositories."